# Can HTMLUnit enter data in password fields?

Tags: java, html, testing

My HTMLUnit tests are failing, and I've got a feeling it's because I'm entering a password using the setValueAttribute() method and that for some reason doesn't work. Any ideas? Am I supposed to pass HTMLUnit the encrypted form of the password?

EDIT:

The code to set the pass:

loginForm.getInputByName("loginPassword").setValueAttribute("1234");

Comment: Post some example code, please.

Comment: This is my code: loginForm.getInputByName("frm_login_password").setValueAttribute("foo"); Looks the same. Are you sure that this is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, can you please submit a test case to HtmlUnit user-list, so we investigate further?

Yours,
Ahmed Ashour
http://asashour.blogspot.com/

Comment: Please post the url to the defect here, so we can link it together.

Answer (score 0):

The password field is not encrypted. It is just not rendered as plain text in the browser (dots or stars instead). You can make it visible with a tool, such as Webdeveloper toolbar for Firefox. So this should not be the problem. I am using HtmlUnit myself and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It does work, I have it working.

I would check to make sure you getting the correct input field name.  If not, can you post the stacktrace.

The below code works for me.
form.getInputByName("password").setValueAttribute("1234");